# Facebook connect login window locking in Chrome

Tags: facebook, google-chrome

In the past week or so I have been getting some very odd behavior with my Facebook Connect functionality.  Thus far, I can only duplicate the issue in Chrome (version 13.0.782.112 m).  Everything seems to work in Firefox and IE.

The problem I'm experiencing can be duplicated by (also, you can easily cancel the registration process even if the Facebook Connect piece works because we require a unique user name after that):

1. Open my site in Google Chrome: http://www.thegameeffect.com
2. Click the "Connect with Facebook" button in the bottom-right portion of the header
3. You will likely see a window pop-up if you're already logged in to Facebook.
4. At this point you will be asked to allow certain access to Facebook information (like any other FB Connect option)... Again, you can cancel the registration even after this step.
5. Now, at this point is where the problem seems to be occurring.  The window after step 4 seems to change, but never load... it simply hangs there and has a title if XD Proxy.

So, if I close the window, click the "Connect with Facebook" button again, you will see another blank window that also hangs, however, upon closing that window, the login/registration seems to be successful.  I absolutely can't explain it... And what's worse is that it only happens in Chrome in all the tests I've done...

AND this only started to happen within the past 1-2 weeks; very perplexing.  Any help would be graciously appreciated.

Just for quick reference, I have this code directly below the  tag:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">

      window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
           FB.init({ appId: '<myappid>', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true });            
      };

      (function () {
           var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
           e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1';
           document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
        } ());

 </script>
```

And this is basically the code that gets executed when you click the "Connect with Facebook" button:

```
  function LoginWithFB(returnURL) {
                FB.login(function (response) {
                    // things seem to hang starting here.
                    if (response.session) {
                        // the function hangs before hitting this code, so what's in here isn't terribly significant.

                    }
                    else {
                        // user cancelled login
                        $.fancybox.close();
                    }
                }, { perms: 'email,user_about_me' });                
            }
```

Comment: I'm not sure but have you tried upgrading to OAuth 2.0?

Comment: I don't believe so.... is that a parameter to set in the FB.init call?  I can certainly try that, but it seems odd that the issue only occurs in Chrome.  At this point, I'm happy to try anything though; thanks for the suggestion!  I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: You need to add `oauth  : true` to your [`FB.init()`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.init/) method and then follow the [`FB.login()`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/) example.

Comment: Worked for me on 13.0.782.107 and 15.0.854.0 dev.

Comment: DannyKK - I recently added the customChannelURL to the init call and unfortunately that did not resolve the error; it didn't break anything in the other browsers (where this is working), so I will leave it there per the link you provided.
<br/><br/>
@ifaour - Thanks for the details on this.  I tried adding this setting, and followed the appropriate FB.login example thereafter, but the same error was occurring either way.  And actually, in other browsers it seemed to break what was previously working (it basically thought that the response.authResponse was false, when it should have been true.)

Comment: @boris Smus - Very interesting... I wonder if this is somehow region related, or environment related.  This is just so bizarre.  Thanks for the info!

Comment: I'm having exactly the same problem.

Comment: To clarify, I'm running Chrome 13.0.782.218

Comment: Lads, I think this might be it: http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=6ef81b4e8b4e03ed&hl=en

Are we all testing on localhost?

Answer (score 0):

The problem has vanished in Chrome 13.0.782.220.