# Facebook login hangs at "XD Proxy" when page is installed via Chrome Web Store

Tags: facebook, google-chrome, chrome-web-store

The created the following web application:

http://www.web-allbum.com/

I also added it to the Chrome Web Store:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/idalgghcnjhmnbgbeebpdolhgdpbcplf

The problem is that when go to the Chrome Web Store and install this app the Facebook login windows hangs at a "XD Proxy" window. While the connect itself works, this blank window can confuse the users.

I did my research, and this seems to be a Chrome issue:
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=59285#c26

If you uninstall the app from Chrome, the problem disappears.

Is there any workaround for this problem?

Similar stackoverflow questions:

- [Facebook connect login window locking in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7089422/facebook-connect-login-window-locking-in-chrome)
- [FB.login dialog does not close on Google Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6125254/fb-login-dialog-does-not-close-on-google-chrome)
- [facebook connect blank pop up on chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5922962/facebook-connect-blank-pop-up-on-chrome/7274845#7274845)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4423718/blank-page-with-fb-connect-js-sdk-on-after-permission-request

This is my Facebook connect in case it helps:

```js
    FB.init({
        appId  : window.__FACEBOOK_APP_ID__,
        status : true, // check login status
        cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
        xfbml  : true, // parse XFBML
        channelUrl : window.__MEDIA_URL__ + 'channel.html', // channel.html file
        oauth  : true // enable OAuth 2.0
    });


    FB.XD.Flash.init();
    FB.XD._transport = "flash";

    if (A.networks.facebook.connected) {
        FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
            // Stores the current user ID for later use
            that.network_id = response.authResponse.userID;

            if (!response.authResponse) {
                // no user session available, someone you dont know
                A.networks.facebook.connected = false;
            }
            callback();
        });
    }
    else {
        callback();
    }
};
```

## The Solution

Thanks to the reekogi reply I was able to workaround this issue. Here is the full implementation:

In order to avoid the XD Proxy problem, you have to connecte to Facebook without using the FB.login, this can be achieved by manually redirecting the user to Facebook page.

I had this login function in my code:

```js
_facebook.connect_to_network = function (callback) {
    FB.login(function (response) {
        if (response.authResponse) {
            console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
            FB.api('/me', function (response) {
                // Stores the current user Id for later use
                that.network_id = response.id;
                console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
                callback();
            });
        }
        else {
            console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
            that.connected = false;
            callback();
        }

    }, {scope: window.__FACEBOOK_PERMS__});
};
```

Which I replaced by this code:

```js
_facebook.connect_to_network = function (callback) {
    var url = 'https://www.facebook.com/connect/uiserver.php?app_id=' + window.__FACEBOOK_APP_ID__ + '&method=permissions.request&display=page&next=' + encodeURIComponent(window.__BASE_URL__ + 'authorize-window?my_app=facebook&my_method=login') + '&response_type=token&fbconnect=1&perms=' + window.__FACEBOOK_PERMS__;

    window.open(url);
};
```

The new code opens a popup which connects to Facebook and returns to the url specified in the 'next' parameter. I added some extra parameters in this callback url so that the javascript code could check for it and close the popup.

This code is executed when the Facebook redirects to the callback url:

```js
_facebook.parse_url_params = function () {
    // This is the popup window
    if (URL_PARAMS.my_method === 'login') {
        window.opener.A.networks.facebook.connected = true;
        self.close();
    }
};
```

URL_PARAMS is just a helper object that contains all the url parameters.

I still believe that this is a Chrome issue, but since this workaround has worked and solved my problem I am marking this question as solved.

Comment: Reproduced. Nice question and VERY NICE DESIGN

Comment: I logged a bug for Facebook to try and fix this in their SDK - bug is here: http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/278247488872084

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you call a javascript redirect to get permissions then redirect back to the http://www.web-allbum.com/connected uri?

I described this method in detail here ->
    [Permissions on fan page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7393037/permissions-on-fan-page/7393278#7393278)

**EDIT:**

The method I demonstrated before will be deprecated when OAuth 2.0 comes into the requirements.

Here is the code, adapted for OAauth 2.0 (`response.session` is replaced with `response.authResponse`)

```html
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
theAppId = "YOURAPPID";
redirectUri = "YOURREDIRECTURI"; //This is the page that you redirect to after the user accepts the permissions dialogue

//Connect to JS SDK
FB.init({
    appId  : theAppId,
    cookie: true, 
    xfbml: true, 
    status: true,
    channelURL : 'http://yourdomain.co.uk/channel.html', // channel.html file
    oauth  : true // enable OAuth 2.0
});

//Append to JS SDK to div.fb-root
(function() {
    var e = document.createElement('script');
    e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
    e.async = true;
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
}());

//Check login status and permissions
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
  if (response.authResponse) {
    // logged in and connected user, someone you know
  } else {
    //Redirect to permissions dialogue
    top.location="https://www.facebook.com/connect/uiserver.php?app_id=" + theAppId + "&method=permissions.request&display=page&next=" + redirectUri + "&response_type=token&fbconnect=1&perms=email,read_stream,publish_stream,offline_access";
  }
});

</script>
```

Just tried and tested, worked fine in chrome.

Comment: Redirecting to another page is not possible, the user must be sent back to the login page after the Facebook connection is done. The user might want to connect other networks after the connecting to Facebook

Comment: Ok, but your app seems to check for permissions at the root uri anyway. Couldn't you redirect back to this? Then they still have the option of connecting to other networks.

Comment: I tried to implement you solution, but the response returned by the Facebook login doesn't have a 'session' property. The only properties it has are 'authResponse' and 'status'.

Comment: Apologies, I see that is being deprecated.

session has been replaced with authResponse, I'll post the new way to use the method I posted earlier.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I was able to workaround by avoiding the FB.login and redirecting to the Facebook page.

Comment: No problem, we had this problem a while back and I knew we found a workaround!

Answer (score 2):

I didn't try the solution proposed by Cesar, because I prefer to stick with Facebook's official javascript SDK.

Nevertheless I would like to add a few observations:

- Indeed, the blocking problem only happened on Chrome after installing from Chrome Web Store. Uninstalling the web app solves the problem. (tested with legacy authentication method, without `oauth` 2.0). After closing the XD Proxy popup manually, my application was working properly.
- After switching to asynchronous `FB.init()` and enabling `oauth` 2.0 option, my application would not even get a valid facebook connect status at login time `({authResponse: null, status: "unknown"})`... Again, uninstalling it from the Chrome Web Store, it's working... `({authResponse: Object, status: "connected"})`
- No problem encountered with Safari, in any of these cases.

Comment: Just for the record (and for curious coders), my application is [Play'em](http://www.playem.com/), and its code is stored on [github](https://github.com/adrienjoly/playem). Your feedback, suggestions or contributions, about the code or the site itself, are appreciated. :-)

Comment: I had the issue with the Facebook app in the Chrome Web Store. I uninstalled it an facebook auth worked again.

Answer (score 1):

In IE8 - this can be caused by your flash version.  I tried everything and nothing worked until I disabled flash.  More details from this blog:http://hustoknow.blogspot.com/2011/06/how-facebooks-xdproxyphp-seemed-to-have.html#comment-form

Answer (score 1):

I was experiencing same problem for all browsers. When user clicked "login" button, a popup opened and hanged; and unless user killed browser process, it caused a high load on CPU. If user managed to see "allow" button and click it however, then it appeared a "xd proxy" blank window and nothing happened. That was the problem.

After long investigations, I noticed my new JS code which proxies setInterval/clearInterval/setTimeout/clearTimeout methods, caused this problem. Code is as follows:

```js
window.timeoutList = new Array();
window.intervalList = new Array();

window.oldSetTimeout = window.setTimeout;
window.oldSetInterval = window.setInterval;
window.oldClearTimeout = window.clearTimeout;
window.oldClearInterval = window.clearInterval;

window.setTimeout = function(code, delay) {
    window.timeoutList.push(window.oldSetTimeout(code, delay));
};
window.clearTimeout = function(id) {
    var ind = window.timeoutList.indexOf(id);
    if(ind >= 0) {
        window.timeoutList.splice(ind, 1);
    }
    window.oldClearTimeout(id);
};
window.setInterval = function(code, delay) {
    window.intervalList.push(window.oldSetInterval(code, delay));
};
window.clearInterval = function(id) {
    var ind = window.intervalList.indexOf(id);
    if(ind >= 0) {
        window.intervalList.splice(ind, 1);
    }
    window.oldClearInterval(id);
};
window.clearAllTimeouts = function() {
    for(var i in window.timeoutList) {
        window.oldClearTimeout(window.timeoutList[i]);
    }
    window.timeoutList = new Array();
};
window.clearAllIntervals = function() {
    for(var i in window.intervalList) {
        window.oldClearInterval(window.intervalList[i]);
    }
    window.intervalList = new Array();
};
```

Removing these lines solved my problem. Maybe it helps to who experiences the same.

Comment: Oh, it was my fault. In the code above, I forgot returning actual values and that was the cause. I updated the code [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3141064/how-to-stop-all-timeouts-and-intervals-using-javascript/8524313#8524313) and it is safe now.

Answer (score 1):

Open a new browser tab in Chrome and see if you have the Facebook 'App' installed.  If so, drag it to the bottom right corner to uninstall.  Once uninstalled the XD Proxy will work.

Reference: [facebook connect blank pop up on chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5922962/facebook-connect-blank-pop-up-on-chrome)

Answer (score 0):

Another workaround is to use this code after you call `FB.init()`:

```js
if (/chrome/.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase())) {
    FB.XD._origin = window.location.protocol + '//' + document.domain + '/' + FB.guid();
    FB.XD.Flash.init();
    FB.XD._transport = 'flash';
}
```

The pop-up window remains open and blank, but I found that in my Chrome Web Store app, the authentication goes through when this code is used.

This bug is also filed on Facebook Developers here: http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/278247488872084

Comment: I was already using this workaround when I posted this question on stackoverflow. The problem is that even if the authentication was working the blank window was a no go to me.

Answer (score 0):

It appears this has been fixed in Chrome. No longer happens for us in Mac Chrome 15.0.874.106

Answer (score 0):

I've been experiencing the same issue in IE9, and it seemed to stem from upgrading to Flash Player 10. The answers suggested already did not work for me and I'd lost hope in trying to fix it since finding an [open bug at Facebook](http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=12112) covering it. But [Henson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/229424/henson) has posted [an answer on a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9256756/575530) that fixed it for me. In the JavaScript in my site master I removed the lines

```js
    FB.UIServer.setLoadedNode = function (a, b) {
       //HACK: http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=20168
        FB.UIServer._loadedNodes[a.id] = b;
    };
```

and now it works. (N.B. I have not checked to see if the IE8 issue those lines were intended to overcome returns.)