# Permissions on fan page

Tags: facebook, permissions, facebook-page

How do I get permission on an application I have on a fan page tab and stay on the current tab?

I am collecting permissions on the application fine, but when I put the application onto a tab, it goes haywire seemingly getting caught in a never-ending loop and never going anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this with the JavaScript SDK:

```
//Facebook connection with the JavaScript SDK
FB.init({
    appId: 'YOURAPPID', 
    cookie: true, 
    xfbml: true, 
    status: true });

FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
    //If you have permissions already
    if (response.session) {
        //Do application stuff...
    } 
    else {
        //Redirect browser to the permission dialogue
        top.location="https://www.facebook.com/connect/uiserver.php?app_id=YOURAPPID&method=permissions.request&display=page&next=REDIRECTPAGEURI&response_type=token&fbconnect=1&perms=email,read_stream,publish_stream,offline_access";
    }
});
```

You put in your application ID in the `fb.init` function, and then adjust the redirect for the permissions dialogue so it includes your application ID, the URI you want to re-direct to after the user accepts the permission dialogue, and finally the permissions you want to get (in this case I included email, read stream, publish stream and offline access token).

Comment: Yur mate it does. I have to put the fan page tab url inplace of REDIRECTPAGEURI but it seemed to run through fine. NICE ONE. Cheers

Comment: No worries. If you get a min could you click the tick on the answer, cheers

Comment: You mean click on the "was this helpful"? DONE! Cheers mate. muchop aprpeciated

Comment: ah soz. clicked the tick mate. Thanks